# freenas - mounting a FAT32 partition with the right charset to "the"

Tags: truenas, fat32

I've just started off with FreeNAS and have got a bunch of data (300gb+) I need to get from a FAT32 partition which I need to shift to the FreeNAS ZFS partition.

FreeNAS has successfully mounted the FAT32 partition and can get to the contents, the only issue is that whever I try to do

```
mv, cp, tar
```

or

```
pax
```

to shift or create an archive of the files, it inevitably chokes on a file it finds with an odd character with an

```
Invalid argument
```

warning. The file name will be something like

```
foo?s bar.mp3
```

where the

```
?
```

will have been an apostrophe or such and FreeNAS doesn't understand it.

I understand I can mount the drive with a different charset to overcome this problem but can't find any reference to it online. Please could someone assist with the necessary arguments I need to use with mount and the syntax it takes, please. I can SSH to the box.

TIA

Comment: An example of the sort of command I'm running: <pre>pax -w -v -f videofolder.tar /mnt/Elements/video</pre>

And it will get so far and hit a file containing a "rogue" filename and will throw "Invalid Argument" thus missing out a lot of files.
The idea being I'd expand the tarball in the new ZFS partition.

Comment: This not an answer to your question but, a workaround.  I had the same problem recently but it was on an external hard drive and only about a dozen files so, I just plugged it into another computer and manually renamed the files then plugged back into my FreeNAS box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the charset to use for conversion at mount time. From `man mount` :

> **iocharset=value**
>
> Character set to use for converting between 8 bit characters
>   and 16 bit Unicode characters. The
>   default is iso8859-1. Long filenames
>   are stored on disk in Unicode format.

Specify it in you fstab or through the `-o` switch if you're mounting the FS manually :

```
 mount -t vfat -o iocharset=<value> /dev/<xxx>
```